# How would I make a <div> containing an image constantly repeat on the page after set intervals using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, object

I am currently making a game where a duck appears on the screen after set intervals, I have a div containing a image of a duck, and would like that same div to appear at random intervals during the time limit of the game.

I am aware I might need to use interval, however am not sure if I have to use create element or retrieve the element?

Any ideas?

Comment: Could explain further? Do you need to show the duck in the same position at random intervals and for random duration? Please share some code

Comment: You could have the div style as display none and on the call to setInterval() replace display none with display block or some other style which makes it visible.

Comment: `// Duck movements start
$('button').click(function(){
  var pos = 1;
  var interval = setInterval(frame, 5);
  function frame(){
    if (pos < 0){
      clearInterval(interval);
    }else{
      pos += 1;
      $('.duck').css('margin-left', pos + 'px');

    }
  }
})
`

Comment: this is my code to make a duck move across the screen, but I want the .duck class to be spawn again after a certain amount of time

Comment: can you please post your complete HTML, JS code. If possible JSFiddle too

Answer (score 0):

You can use basic HTML and CSS. Try using image as a background image and then turning on repeat.
background-image: url("pics/home.jpg");
                 background-position:100px 25px;

Comment: but I want to make the same div appear appear after set intervals

Answer (score 0):

I think you should separate the code to move the duck out of the click handler and into a separate function. Then in the click handler call the new moveDuck() function. At the end of moveDuck as well as clearing the interval, set a timeout which calls moveDuck again after another amount of time.

Something like this:

```
$('button').click(moveDuck);
var interval;

function moveDuck() {
  var pos = 1; 
  interval = setInterval(frame, 5); 
}

function frame() { 
  if (pos < 0) { 
    clearInterval(interval); 
    setTimeout(moveDuck, 1000); //start again shortly
  }
  else { 
    pos += 1; 
    $('.duck').css('margin-left', pos + 'px'); 
  } 
}
```

The only thing with this is, from your code I cannot see how `pos` ever ends up being less than 0, but perhaps there is something else you didn't mention.